# Meteor Update Template Element based on Interval

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

I am new to Meteor. Basically, I want to update an element (for example {{title}}) that is acquired from a collection within some sort of interval of time; like fetching the next title from the collection for each 20 seconds.

In ajax i can easily construct a function with timer to pull the data from the server side. How can this be achieved in Meteor framework?

I know that the collection can be declared/initialized like this

```
Template.mytemplate.title = function {
  return Titles.find();
}
```

but I do not plan on using `#each` to looping show all of them. I plan to show them one by one at a specific interval of time.

Please advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply update the data you want to display in an interval. For example:

```
Template.myTemplate.title = function() {
  return Titles.find({}, {
    limit: 1,
    skip: Session.get('offset'),
  }).fetch();
};

Template.myTemplate.created = function() {
  Session.set('offset', 0);
  setInterval(function() {
    Session.set('offset', Session.get('offset') + 1);
  }, 20000);
};
```

Comment: I am having difficulties in understanding the parameters in the Titles.find()... I can see that offet value is fetched from session but when we update the session, will it automatically refresh the offset?

Comment: I managed to refresh the template every couple seconds but I cannot move to the next item inthe collection. After i update the offset variable in the `created` event, the title still shows the no 1.

Comment: Session is reactive object, it means every time Sesion.get("offset") changes then query ( Title.find(...) ) is being rerun and template is updated automatically.

Comment: @KubaWyrobek Didnt work for me. I read the documentation on collection.find(), is the offset one of the option?

Comment: @HubertOG @KubaWyrobek I found it! Should have used `skip` instead of `offset`. Hubert, please correct it so that I can mark it as answer.

Comment: Right, I meant `skip`. Apologies, I'm working on a SQL task at this moment :-)

Comment: And yes, since `Session` is reactive, it will automatically refresh its value when you set it, as long as you get it inside a thing called reactive computation – for example a data helper. [More on the topic in this section of Meteor documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#deps).